# Make div background color span entire width

Tags: css

What I'm trying to do is have a bootstrap like navbar where the actual navbar is around 960px in the center but have the background color span the entire width of the window.

However, when the window is less than 960px in width, and I scroll, the background doesn't go all the way to the end.

[image]

Is it possible to make this happen without having custom rules for max-width(960px)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #nav {
        height: 33px;
        background-color: #cfcfcf;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <div id="container">
        test
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Oops. Had an extra  in there, though that wasn't the issue.

Comment: Funny, it works fine in Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
body {
    min-width:960px;
}
```

which seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The height has to be in the inner div (#container).
try

```
#nav { background-color: #cfcfcf; }

#container {  
    height:33px;
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/wYGLj/

Answer (score 0):

You need your nav div to span the entire page.

`#nav { width:100%; }`

will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is working as it should.  So if you want it to extent the whole length of the screen, create a `wrapper` to handle that grey element. Like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #cfcfcf;
    }
    #container {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #nav {
        height: 33px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="nav">
    <div id="container">
        test
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```